# ToolStripItem will appear in a bad position

Tags: c#

I wrote below code.but when i click on menu "select" , it's sub item("Radio") will appear at the top and left side of the page.i put it's picture.
"_zz" is my ToolStripMenuItem and its text is "select".

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        MakeItems();
    }

      void MakeItems()
    {


        var item = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem()
        {
            Name = "Test1",
            Text = "Tv"
        };

        _zz.DropDownItems.Add(item);

        }
    private void _zz_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _zz.DropDown.Items.Count; i++)
        {
             _zz.DropDown.Items[i].Dispose();

        }
        MakeItems2();
    }

  void MakeItems2()
    {

        var item2 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem()
        {
            Name = "Test2",
            Text = "Radio"
        };

        _zz.DropDownItems.Add(item2);

    }
```

[pic url](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=kb3w93&s=8)

Answer (score 0):

The default location is at (0,0) this is the top left corner , you can change the location of "radio" like this:

```
    void MakeItems2()
    {

        var item2 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem()
        {
            Name = "Test2",
            Text = "Radio",
            Location = new Point(100,100)
        };

        _zz.DropDownItems.Add(item2);

    }
```

Comment: thanks but is not a good solution. because i do not have just one item ,"Radio,..." . they will add dynamically. and i can not change location of all of them.